# Simple D3: circles not appending to svg element

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I'm trying to render a simple D3 scatterplot - the svg element is present in the DOM but upon inspection the circle elements do not exist in the rendered html.  The program compiles successfully.  Any hints for a d3 newbie?  (I successfully rendered circles by importing a .csv file but am curious as to why declaring the data array of objects here doesn't seem to work as expected.).

````
import React from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

const Graph = () => {

  const data = [{ x: 100, y: 200 }, { x: 200, y: 400 }, { x: 300, y: 600 }]; 

  d3.select('svg')
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('r', 5)
    .attr('fill', 'blue')
    .attr('cx', d => d['x'])
    .attr('cy', d => d['y']);

  return (
    <>
      <svg id='graph1' width='400' height='800' style={{ background: 'lightgrey' }}/>
    </>
  );
};

export default Graph;```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like you need to render the svg BEFORE you append the data?

d3.select('svg')

is selecting nothing and therefore appending the data to nothing..

Answer (score 0):

A solution includes using a reference to the svg element and a useEffect() to render the circles after the svg element has been rendered initially:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

const data = [{ x: 200, y: 100 }, { x: 400, y: 200 }, { x: 600, y: 300 }]; 

const Graph = () => {

  const svgRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const svg = d3.select(svgRef.current);

    svg
      .selectAll('circle')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('r', 5)
      .attr('fill', 'blue')
      .attr('cx', d => d['x'])
      .attr('cy', d => d['y']);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <svg id='graph1' ref={svgRef} width='800' height='400' style={{ background: 'lightgrey' }}/>
    </>
  );
};

export default Graph;
```

Answer (score 0):

I Achieve this goal with this code...please have a look I hope it's helpful for others.

```
import "./styles.css";
import * as d3 from "d3";
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
const data = [
  { x: 100, y: 100 },
  { x: 150, y: 100 }
];
export default function App() {
  const svgRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const svg = d3.select(svgRef.current);
    svg
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", (d) => d["x"])
      .attr("cy", (d) => d["y"])
      .attr("r", 20)
      .attr("fill", "red");

  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <svg ref={svgRef}></svg>
    </div>
  );
}
```